# How to use angular-cli inside VS 2015?

Tags: javascript, node.js, visual-studio, angular, npm

Is That possibole to use https://github.com/angular/angular-cli inside VS 2015?

I tried to open my Webstorm project inside VS but the node command doesnt know anything like "ng".

I thought the same commands of node and npm works inside Websotrm and VS.

Comment: most likely, VS is using it's own installed version of node, and thus does not have access to node 4.x or any of it's installed modules.  There are a few tutorials out there about how to synchronize the node install for VS, like http://ryanhayes.net/synchronize-node-js-install-version-with-visual-studio-2015/ for example

Comment: Did you try to `npm i -g angular-cli` from VS?